# Delete Custom Permissions is NOT working -getting error -site is not shared with you

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, item-added, custom-permission-level

i have created a event receiver on a doc lib with itemadded, itemupdated event receiver that provides permissions on the item for multiple groups and multiple users.
for this i have created a permission level called npd deleteilp, that has the delete privileges on the item.

[image: delete-permissions1]

[image: site-notshared]

delete custom permissions level
 [image: delete-custom-permissions-level]

my item event fires successfully and applies the security correctly  but when i try to login with that userid who has the delete permissions, i am unable to delete the item/document , but am getting error

> "sorry this site is not shared with you"

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to have a limited permission on the site level as well. right now you have permission on the item and not on the site on which the item resides. There should be a limited access permission on the site to access the contents with unique permission.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate, what i need to do for achieving this? i have enabled - for create major versions radio button for this doc lib. and made teh require content approval for submtted items as NO.

Comment: go to the site level permission settings and assign a read or view only permission for the user to the site and then check if user are able to perform the action

Comment: i have already added him in the HOME VISITORS default group and tried again. but the same issue persists.